# How to write to a folder in a Azure Data Lake container using Delta?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

How do I write to a folder in an Azure Data Lake container using Delta?

When I run:

```py
    write_mode = 'overwrite'
    write_format = 'delta'
    save_path = '/mnt/container-name/folder-name'
     
    df.write \
        .mode(write_mode) \
        .format(write_format) \
        .save(save_path)
```

I get an incompatible format error. **This does not happen when I write directly to the container** ('/mnt/container-name').

I have also tried writing using the SQL commands but I get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it looks like you have some data in the folder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you cannot save to a folder within a delta table. The mistake that I made was I saved the delta table directly to the container and then tried to save another delta table to a folder within this container.

When I saved to a folder within a container that only had folders in it, I did not get this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check weather in this path is there any data Available or not `/mnt/container-name/folder-name` and also check storage connection between the data lake and data bricks .

Otherwise ***Create mount*** and ***Create a storage*** connection between the data lake and data bricks.Follow below steps.

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.blobstoragename.dfs.core.windows.net",dbutils.secrets.get(scope="scopename",key="keyvalue"))
```

***Create mount***

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
source = "wasbs://containername@blobstoragename.blob.core.windows.net",
mount_point = "/mnt/iotd/fgh",
extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key. blobstoragename.blob.core.windows.net":" past Access key "})
```

**For example**, to overwrite the [data in a table](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-batch.html#overwrite-using-dataframes) you can:

```
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/mnt/container-name/folder-name")
```

**Reference:**

https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/azure-datalake-gen2-get-started.html

[Table batch reads and writes - Azure Databricks | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/delta-batch)

[Table batch reads and writes — Delta Lake Documentation](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-batch.html#overwrite-using-dataframes&language-sql)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cbobqI3ZGuA